# Is there an alternative to using yap.exe for rendering dvi files within MikTeX?

Tags: programming, software

I have used MiKTeX and the book document class for mathematics layout for more than 10 years with little trouble. The "build" command always runs successfully but, just recently, the "build and show output" command runs on forever - no matter what the size of the text file.  Is this a problem with the yap.exe program and, if so, is there an alternative piece of software available - even if one has to pay!  I have re-installed MiKTeX and Technic Center more than once - both as a user and as an administrator to no avail.

Comment: You can use TeX Live and `xdvi`, but honestly why not simply convert to PDF and use a PDF viewer?

Comment: I personally find the the dvi output to be much easier to interrogate for editing purposes, but I would like to press the point... what has changed, and why is the yap.exe program so unpredictable?  This is a digital issue!

Comment: We can only offer such advice as is _generally_ available in the community: specific issues with binaries are typically best reported as issues to their maintainers, in this case Christian Schenk.

Comment: @Joseph Wright I have today visited the website offered by Christian Schenk and made an attempt to highlight this issue.  I'm afraid I'm not familiar with the jargon used within "git" - have to wait for a possible reply.

Comment: @JosephWright No reply from Christian Schenk.  I've tried to use the pdf viewer as you suggest, but the text is covered with red outlines. I cannot find a way to remove these, for example.  That is why I am reluctant to change from dvi.  This must apply to many users, since there are many subscribers to MiKTeX.

Comment: Almost everyone is using PDF-based routes nowadays - and those using DVI are likely converting to PDF to view as this avoids issues with specials. I've no idea what you mean about red outlines - I wonder if you've got some specials that are not being rendering in your DVI (so the output you are used to is misleading).

Comment: Note that Christian isn't active here: several of us do have contact with him from time to time, but it's entirely up to him what he responds to

Comment: Which pdf viewer are you using that covers the text with red outlines?  Are those hyperlinks that hyperref is highlighting?  What is the smallest document that takes forever to compile and display with yap?  MikTeX supports forward and inverse searching, so I'm not sure what you mean by dvi being easier to interrogate for editing purposes.  Could you elaborate?

Comment: If the build command doesn't terminate, this can be due to one or some of your .tex-input-files containing code which forms an infinite loop. || Another possibility might be some badly configured anti-malware-software blocking MiKTeX's executables.

Comment: Open an issue at https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues. And do not forget to add small but complete example. Try also to compile on the terminal (latex file) and then open the dvi manually in yap to exclude a problem with your texnic center setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you install MiKTeX freshly, the default render setting for yap.exe uses pks.
Open yap.exe without a target file and go to view>options>display. Set the the display to dvips.  Open a dvi file in order to save your new setting.